# How to make layout from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this select query (view) like this:

```
SELECT ArticleID, period, SUM(Amount) As Total 
FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries 
WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY ArticleID, period
```

That returns me this:

[image]

Is it possible to write a select statement that would return the data like this:

[image]

Comment: Only till 201703 or going next upto 201708 also?

Comment: It should take all periods that are available. Thanks.

Comment: Try searching Dynamic Pivot.

Comment: If you are looking for a sql server specific implementation then look into the PIVOT command.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a sql server here to test this but should be something like:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(period)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT period FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL) AS periods

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT , ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (SELECT
    ArticleID, period, Amount
    FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries 
    WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL 
    ) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(Amount) 
          FOR period IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

More information on this for MS Sql Server can be found [here](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17189123)

Comment: Added the sample

Answer (score 1):

You can to do this:

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT ArticleID, [201701], [201702], [201703], [201708]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries 
    WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL 
) T
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Amount)
  FOR period IN ([201701], [201702], [201703], [201708])
) P;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to add all available periods in the table (not hard-code them), maybe sub-select would do?

Comment: @Benua you're welcome. If you could to descriminate the columns in sub-select, you can use `*` on Select outside. On the `PIVOT` you could use dinamic query, like @Jester 's answer